# iOS Simulator Network Call failing on Xcode 12.4 with Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1017

Tags: ios, swift, xcode12, urlsession

Am making a loop of network calls using URLSession. Network calls failing with below error. Using Mac Bigger and Xcode 12.4

```
Task <C02793A3-B012-4524-8261-E61E8302D235>.<6> finished with error [-1017] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1017 "cannot parse response" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-1, NSUnderlyingError=0x600001a99140 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1017 "(null)" UserInfo={NSErrorPeerAddressKey=<CFData 0x60000348c000 [0x7fff8002eb50]>{length = 16, capacity = 16, bytes = 0x100222b87f0000010000000000000000}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-1, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <C02793A3-B012-4524-8261-E61E8302D235>.<6>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <C02793A3-B012-4524-8261-E61E8302D235>.<6>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=cannot parse response, NSErrorFailingU
```